# Mixed Methods Analysis of Variance with a maximum likelihood approach

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, ancova, predictor

I am having trouble with a major analysis change suggested by a reviewer for my paper.  I will start by stating what I did in the paper:

I was interested in seeing subjective interest in two types of films presented to participants.  I conducted a 2x2x2 mixed-methods ANCOVA using the GL approach.  More specifically, my IVs are-- IV1: gender (man/woman), IV2: film type (control/sports), IV3: presentation order (control film first, sport film first); CV: tv consumption (measured on a 7 point scale from "never" to "daily").  My DV was subjective enjoyment, measured on a 7 point scale (from "no enjoyment" to "extremely enjoyable").  Gender and presentation order are between-subjects factor, film presentation is a within-subjects factor.

The reviewer stated that she felt this was an incorrect analysis given that a) it was likely that my regression lines for the CV and DV are nonparallel, and b) my CV is not on an interval scale.  Thus, she stated she thought I should conduct a "mixed method analysis of variance for which you could use a maximum likelihood approach".  After tons of research I think I understand how to conduct this, but I'm still confused as to why this would be better.  My major question is: I am still adding the CV to my MIXED ANCOVA, so don't I run into the same problems with violating the assumptions of a covariate?